# CA certificate name contrains issue with regard to Common Name (CN=)

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, pki

Can someone please confirm (or better still tell me a why I can achieve the following if it is at all possible) my understanding/issue

I use a Microsoft CA (Domain Joined) from what I have read here and on other blogs posts I cannot use name contrains to restrict the issuance of certifcates when the domain name I want to restrict appears **only in the Common Name** (e.g. CN=) part of the overal subject name field.

for example

lets say I want to restrict the issuance of any certificate for **MyDomain.com**

if I have a certificate signing request which includes a Subject Name of

CN=www.MyDomain.com,OU=IT,O=MyOrg,L=Poole,S=Dorset,C=GB

Also there is **no subject alternatives names** in the certificate signing request at all.

although I have name contrains in my CA certificate under the DNS (exclusion) section e.g.

DNS = .MyDomain.com
DNS =  MyDomain.com

The CA will still issue a certificate.

If I then add something like www2.MyDomain.com to the SAN of the certificate signing request the CA rejects the request as expected

So from what I have seen and read, name contrains do not apply to the CN= (common name) element of the Subject Name?

As WEB Servers SSL/TLS will look at CN= for domain name match (if no SAN is present) to accept a certificate, looks like there is no solution to this, unless I am missing something?

I would be grateful for any input

thanks
__AAnotherUser

Answer (score 2):

From [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.10):

> Applications conforming to this profile MUST be able to process name
> constraints that are imposed on the directoryName name form and
> SHOULD be able to process name constraints that are imposed on the
> rfc822Name, uniformResourceIdentifier, dNSName, and iPAddress name
> forms.

Constraints on the directory name (of which the CN is a part) and on a dNSName (which is a subjectAltName) are two different types of constraints, both of which have to be present in the CA certificate.

Btw: Server certificates without a SAN are not allowed anymore by the CA/Browser Forum.